# Three.js - How to replace the model of an Object3D?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to replace an `object3D` with a `character` model, with another one, while keeping all it's properties, such as the position

```
var object = new THREE.Object3D( );
object = models.character[0].clone( );
object.position.set( 100, 230, 15 );
scene.add( object.scene );

const clip = THREE.AnimationClip.findByName( object.animations, 'idle' );
var action = mixer.clipAction( clip );
action.play();

//...later on, replace the model, while keeping it's position

object = models.character[1].clone( );
```

How do I replace the model of an `THREE.Object3D( )`?

Answer (score 1):

An `Object3D` doesn't have a model because it doesn't have geometry or materials. This line of code doesn't do anything because you're immediately replacing the Object3D with something else:

```
var object = new THREE.Object3D( );
object = models.character[0].clone( );
```

I think you should be using a `Mesh`, which is a subclass of Object3D. Now, if you want to change the "model" of a `Mesh`, you can access its `.geometry` property, and assign it a new one:

```js
// This is the original geometry
const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
mesh.position.set(100, 230, 15);

// Here we assign a new geometry to the Mesh
mesh.geometry = someOtherGeometry;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for -- but THREE.Mesh(geometry, material) doesn't work with `gltf` models.. E.g: `const geometry = models.character[0].clone( );` doesn't work